# getting the most recent row, grouped by an attribute's value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a questionnaire for users to fill out. Users can answer each question many times. Responses have a question_key to pair them with their question. I want to get the full set of a user's current responses without retrieving every response created by a user.

The responses table looks like this:

```
create_table "responses", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "question_key", :null => false
  t.text     "value",        :null => false
  t.integer  "user_id",      :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Here's the relevant part of the response class:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current
    recent.uniq {|response| response.question_key}
  end

  scope :recent, order('created_at DESC')
end
```

`user.responses.current` gets the set of responses, but it seems really inefficient. It's getting all of the responses ever created by a user, and then throwing away everything but the most recent one for each unique value of `question_key`

I did figure out a SQL query that does what I want, ordering the rows before doing GROUP BY. Is there a reasonable way to use this in Response::current?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM responses
    WHERE user.id = 6
    ORDER BY created_at DESC ) as user_responses
GROUP BY question_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution relies on the ids being sequential:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current
    where(id: group(:question_key).maximum(:id).values)
  end
end
```

It results in two queries when getting the current responses for a user (`user.responses.current`), but it avoids returning all of the user's responses.

```
SELECT MAX(`responses`.`id`) AS maximum_id, question_key AS question_key FROM `responses` WHERE `responses`.`user_id` = 6 GROUP BY question_key
SELECT `responses`.* FROM `responses` WHERE `responses`.`user_id` = 6 AND `responses`.`id` IN (452, 447, 9, 225, 190, 230, 240)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a group by in active record by using the `group` method.

`Responses.where(user_id: '123').order('created_at DESC').group('question_key')`

So your code would be something like:

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, order('created_at DESC')
  def self.current
    recent.group('question_key')
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this, and it does `group by` before `order by` - returning the oldest response for each question. Using your code, this is the resulting SQL:

    `SELECT 'responses'.* FROM 'responses' WHERE 'responses'.'user_id' = 1011645 GROUP BY question_key ORDER BY created_at DESC`